# how to use start date end date calendar in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

I am using Selenium IDE for testing ,when I select the both start date and end date but  i replay the script they showing the start date.

Selenium script code is here :--

```
selenium.click("id=start");
     selenium.click("//tr[5]/td[3]");
         selenium.click("css=td.active.day");
              selenium.click("css=td.active.day");
                       selenium.click("id=Due");
                            selenium.click("//tr[6]/td[7]");
                                selenium.click("css=td.active.day");
                                 selenium.click("css=td.active.day");
```

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: Yes, code is uploaded

Comment: I use the click At command then resolve my issue.